# Собрать несколько бинарников cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, build

Имеется клиент-сервер проект, содержание cmakelist следующее:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(chatProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(COMMON_SOURCES common/socketWrapper.h common/color.h)
set(SERVER_SOURCES server/main.cpp)
set(CLIENT_SOURCES client/main.cpp client/client.h client/message.h)

add_executable(client ${COMMON_SOURCES} ${CLIENT_SOURCES})
add_executable(server ${COMMON_SOURCES} ${SERVER_SOURCES})
```

Проблема : собирается по умолчанию только клиент. Подскажите пожалуйста, как собирать и клиент,и сервер вместе.

Comment: а если писать на `make`, а `make all` ?

Comment: @KoVadim, тоже вариант,но ниже описали по-моему решение получше

Comment: но он рабочий ? (make all)

Comment: @KoVadim да, работает) спасибо

Comment: вот - просто Вы натолкнулись на нормальную работу make - когда он не пересобирает то, что не нужно пересобирать.  Но может и бажинка там есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разбей на 2 CMakeLists.txt.

В Первом сделай для клиента настройку:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(client)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(COMMON_SOURCES common/socketWrapper.h common/color.h)
set(CLIENT_SOURCES client/main.cpp client/client.h client/message.h)

add_executable(client ${COMMON_SOURCES} ${CLIENT_SOURCES})
```

Во втором для сервера:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(server)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(COMMON_SOURCES common/socketWrapper.h common/color.h)
set(SERVER_SOURCES server/main.cpp)

add_executable(server ${COMMON_SOURCES} ${SERVER_SOURCES})
```

Затем добавь ещё один корневой CMakeLists.txt и добавь туда:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(chatProject)

add_subdirectory(path/to/client)
add_subdirectory(path/to/server)

add_custom_target(chatProject)
add_dependencies(chatProject client server)
```

и делай make конкретно chatProject или из папки где лежит рутовый CMakeLists.txt. Такая организация будет самая правильная.

Если будет добавляться какая-то дополнительная логика в разные части (сервер/клиент), то не будешь засорять один CMake.

Comment: спасибо огромное, внесли ясность)